# Problem using getJSON and YQL

Tags: jquery, json, yql

I'm trying to get the views of a video in Youtube through YQL to display it on my site, I'm using jQuery's `$.getJSON` method to get the result of the YQL call which I do fine but for some reason the success part isn't firing, here's my code:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DrWlHtvZHbZ8%26feature%3Dplayer_embedded%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D'%2Fhtml%2Fbody%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%5B3%5D%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%5B3%5D%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%5B2%5D%2Fdiv%2Fspan%2Fstrong'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc",
    function(data) {
        alert('Hello');
    }
);
```

I see on my firebug's console that the request is made and it's returning the correct json object but the alert in my function isn't firing, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `&callback=cbfunc` from the URL, so jQuery can define the callback itself.

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DrWlHtvZHbZ8%26feature%3Dplayer_embedded%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D'%2Fhtml%2Fbody%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%5B3%5D%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%5B3%5D%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%5B2%5D%2Fdiv%2Fspan%2Fstrong'&format=json&diagnostics=true",
    function(data) {
        alert('Hello');
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/C5cYB/

Answer (score 1):

It is considered bad practice to use jQuery's anonymous callbacks, see [Beware of client-side libraries "helping" you](http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2010/03/12/avoiding-rate-limits-and-getting-banned-in-yql-and-pipes-caching-is-your-friend/) on the YQL blog.

Since your original YQL URL told YQL to expect a callback function called `cbfunc`, then all you need to do is define that function in your JavaScript (in the `window` scope).

```
function cbfunc(data) {
    alert('Hello');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about YQL, but I see an explicit callback set at the end of that querystring, which could be a problem. Have you tried removing "callback=cbfunc", or putting "callback=?" as in the jsonp documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/